# UIScrollViews all scroll in the same time

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a screen with several scrollViews. How to achieve this:
When i tap on one and swipe they all start to scroll. I of course know `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods and what i trying to do so far is combine `-setContentOffset:animated:` with `scrollViewDidScroll` and it works but only for one case - when i start scrolling with delegate scrollview.

How to dynamically change delegate? depends which scroll view user select?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep an array of all of your `UIScrollView` objects. Make sure all of their delegates point to the same object (or if that's not possible, there is some sort of handler that gets called on `scrollViewDidScroll`). Then use `setContentOffset` to adjust the offsets. You had the right idea, but you just want to make sure all scroll views except the current view (which is determined by the delegate method argument) is scrolling.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  for (UIScrollView *view in self.scrollViews) {
    if (scrollView != view) {
      [view setContentOffset:scrollView.contentOffset];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. That's my issue. When i have for example 5 scrollviews in array and I set delegate to the first one other will scroll only when i start scrolling the first one. What I want to do here is start scrolling all scroll views no matter which user will touch.

Comment: You want to set all of the `UIScrollView`'s `delegate`s to the same object, which might be a view controller.