# How to scroll three UIScrollViews at the same time?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I'm creating an app which is Course Table. I want to display the table in the window. Like this:

[image: the upper represents week, the left represents timeline and bottom-left represents courses]

> the upper represents week, the left represents timeline and 
>   bottom-left represents courses

Because the `UIImageView` is so big that the iPhone window can't display it full, then I use three `UIScrollViews` to represent the course table. My idea is to move the bottom-left  `UIScrollView` by hand, and automatically scroll three `UIScrollViews` at the same time. But I can't achieve it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152602/uiscrollviews-all-scroll-in-the-same-time?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
//grab scroll offset of scrolled uiscrollview
CGPoint scrollOffsetOne = self.scrollViewOne.contentOffset;

//apply that offset to the others
self.scrollViewTwo.contentOffset = scrollOffsetOne;
self.scrollViewThree.contentOffset = scrollOffsetOne;
```

Comment: Refer to @jamihash 's comment. Already solved it. It's my implement: http://www.cnblogs.com/submarine/archive/2012/12/09/2810555.html

Comment: But I write this blog in simplified Chinese. Save two UIScrollView objects in a NSArray object, then customize -scrollViewDidScroll: method.